# How to implement chain operations in Python?

Tags: python

```
class Array:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []

    def add(self, num):
        self.list.append(num)

a = Array()
a.add(1).add(2)
```

I would like to add number 1, 2 to self.list like this.
How can I implement?

Comment: `return self` from `add`

Comment: probably relevant for OP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688966/let-a-class-behave-like-its-a-list-in-python/36690145

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python way for object method chaining for class instance variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846202/python-way-for-object-method-chaining-for-class-instance-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your insertion returns the instance itself for second operation, then you will have instance itself so you can perform add operation:

```
def add(self, num):
    self.list.append(num)
    return self
```

Answer (score 1):

Return the object itself

```
def add(self, num):
    self.list.append(num)
    return self
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach, why not just let your `add` method take a list of values as input? Seems like it would be easier to use like that

```
def add(self, vals):
    self.list += vals
```

So now you can

```
a.add([1,2])
```

Instead of

```
a.add(1).add(2)
```